# Htaccess CSS not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /games4u/
RewriteRule    ^index/?$    index.php    [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^forum/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ forum.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ forum.php?user=$1
```

So what I want is the url to be: localhost/forum/1
1 = user id 1. But the design wont load because of this. It's like the CSS file gets removed or something. Why doesn't thios work?

Comment: Open the site in Firefox with Firebug, or Chrome with Developer Tools, so that you can see what URL gets actually called to retrieve the CSS. If you use relative paths, it is possible that they get rewritten to something different from what you expect. For example "src=test.css" would cause "forum/test.css" (or forum/1/test.css) to be requested.

Answer (score 1):

When you add extra `/` slashes in the URL, that changes what the relative URL base becomes. The browser doesn't know that `/games4u/` is the base for relative URL's generated by the forum.php code. Now that you've added another level of folders, `/games4u/forum/username`, the browser attempts to resolve relative URLs by adding the base: `/games4u/forum/` to all the links. You need to specify your base in the page headers or make all your links absolute (starts with `/games4u/`):

```
<base href="/games4u/" />
```

The `RewriteBase` directive has nothing to do with the relative URL base on the browser. The browser doesn't even know you're using rewrite rules. The `RewriteBase` directive is only for relative paths in your `RewriteRule`s.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set conditions for your re-writing, to ignore folders and files:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /games4u/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^index/?$    index.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ forum.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^forum/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ forum.php?user=$1
```

Also, it's recommended that you will use the full path for your css / js files, such as:

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/js/file.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using `REQUEST_FILENAME` in this case will not make a difference as the included assets are more than likely not named similarly to the paths specified in the original rules. In addition, those two conditions will only affect the first rule. However, the second part of your answer is correct.